# How to use tfp.layers.IndependentNormal in Keras TimeDistributed layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-probability

This model works fine without any error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Bidirectional, LSTM, Dropout, Dense, TimeDistributed
import tensorflow_probability as tfp


model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(100, 1), ))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))

print(model.summary())
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 100, 32)           2304      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 100, 32)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 100, 16)           3136      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 100, 16)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 100, 16)           2112      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 100, 16)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri (None, 100, 1)            17        
=================================================================
Total params: 7,569
Trainable params: 7,569
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

But after I changed the line `model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))` to `model.add(TimeDistributed(tfp.layers.IndependentNormal(1)))`, this model run with an error.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx.py", line 27, in <module>
    model.add(TimeDistributed(tfp.layers.IndependentNormal(1)))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 530, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 217, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 977, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1115, in _functional_construction_call
    inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 848, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 888, in _infer_output_signature
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/wrappers.py", line 271, in call
    output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/wrappers.py", line 190, in compute_output_shape
    child_output_shape = self.layer.compute_output_shape(child_input_shape)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/tf_utils.py", line 259, in wrapper
    output_shape = fn(instance, input_shape)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 867, in compute_output_shape
    return super(Lambda, self).compute_output_shape(input_shape)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 790, in compute_output_shape
    return tf.nest.map_structure(lambda t: t.shape, outputs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 869, in map_structure
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 869, in <listcomp>
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 790, in <lambda>
    return tf.nest.map_structure(lambda t: t.shape, outputs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/keras_tensor.py", line 131, in shape
    return self._type_spec._shape  # pylint: disable=protected-access
AttributeError: 'UserRegisteredSpec' object has no attribute '_shape'
```

So how to use tfp.layers.IndependentNormal layer in Keras TimeDistributed layer?

Thank you so much for helping me.

============================================================

The version of packages used in this project:

Keras: 2.6.0

TensorFlow: 2.6.2

TensorFlow-probability: 0.14.1

Comment: Tested and working with the versions you mentioned above.

Comment: @JM Zhou, Tested and working with latest versions of `TF2.8`, `Keras 2.8` and `tensorflow_probability 0.16`. Please refer [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/chunduriv/0fc7d0574f25702fefb41576c5caec8c/71389398.ipynb) for reference. Thanks!